Azure Web App + Database Deployment Error
I am trying to follow along a tutorial from Microsoft (Tutorial: Deploy a PHP, MySQL, and Redis app to Azure App Service) and whenever I try to create and deploy a WebApp in Azure, I always get the same error.
{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "The subscription '8f036b21-0671-48cb-b0e5-173b76e7e***' is not allowed to create or update the serverfarm.",
    "details": [
        {
            "message": "The subscription '8f036b21-0671-48cb-b0e5-173b76e7e***' is not allowed to create or update the serverfarm."
        },
        {
            "code": "Forbidden"
        },
        {}
    ]
}

}
Am I missing something? This is my private account and I am the owner of the subscription and yet it still says that this subscription has no rights. Is there a setting I have to change or something I might have messed up already?
Please let me know if you need more information.

Is your subscription a trial?

Hi @KonTheCat, yes, I am on the free account subscription with 200$ of use as a first time user.

According to this thread this seems to be an issue for more people at this time.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1527674/the-subscription-is-not-allowed-to-create-or-updat?page=3#answers

@Eas - Can you please share the tutorial which you are following?

Hi @Harshitha, thank you for your response. I have tried several tutorials and I always get the same issue. The PHP one too. I have the Owner Role. I have tried other regions to no avail. But I will give it a shot again one of these days, since in the Microsoft community thread, people keep saying that they have the issue still.

I have followed the MSDoc Tutorial: PHP app with MySQL and Redis and able to deploy the Web App to Azure App Service without any issue.

Yes, as per the MS Q&A the issue is with registering the Server farm and sometimes the issue can be caused temporarily.

Try to redeploy the app once again.

Also, cross check the permissions for your Subscription.

I have  the Contributor role



Git Hub Deployment:

Deployment Logs:

Environment Variables:


If you still face the issue, try to create the App Service in another region.

Also refer this SOThread which address the same issue.
